# API Foreach resulting in invalid arguments

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

Okay, so I am trying to use a restful api. And when I put my results into a foreach loop, I get that the variable in that foreach is undefined. What do I need to do instead?

My results are coded as `$modules` and when I `var_dump` this, I receive the following array:

```
string(42) "array ( 1 => 'Emails', 2 => 'Pages', )"
```

Now, When I try to place this in my foreach loop like so:

```
<?php foreach($modules as $module => $name): ?>
    <?php echo $module; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I get this error:

```
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Btw, I am using codeigniter and the `$modules` are passed from a controller to a view.

`$data['modules'] = codeToGetArray`

**update**

The code that is supposed to be making the array is as follows:

```
function list_get()
{
    $this->load->model('api/api_m', 'api_m');

    $modules = $this->api_m->list_modules();

    $mods = array();

    foreach($modules as $module)
    {
        $mods[$module->id] = $module->name;
    }

    $modules = $mods;

    if($modules)
    {
        $this->response($modules, 200);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t fin any modules!'), 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer based on your comment, but you should update the question to reflect the fixed typo

Answer (score 0):

Function [var_dump()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) should show array not string. It is not foreach fault but somewhere before in code where string is made.